# The difference between Task.Factory.FromAsync and BeginX/EndX?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have very similar code when using the standard BeginRead and EndRead methods from the TcpClient and using Task.Factory.FromAsync.

Here are some examples.. Error handling code not shown.

**Task.Factory.FromAsync:**

```
private void Read(State state)
{
    Task<int> read = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(state.Stream.BeginRead, state.Stream.EndRead, state.Bytes, state.BytesRead, state.Bytes.Length - state.BytesRead, state, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    read.ContinueWith(FinishRead);
}

private void FinishRead(Task<int> read)
{
    State state = (State)read.AsyncState;

    state.BytesRead += read.Result;
}
```

**Standard use of callbacks with BeginRead and EndRead:**

```
private void Read(State state)
{
    client.BeginRead(state.Bytes, state.BytesRead, state.Bytes.Length - state.Bytes.Read, FinishRead, state);
}

private void FinishRead(IAsyncResult async)
{
    State state = (State)async.AsyncState;

    state.BytesRead += state.Stream.EndRead(async);
}
```

Both of these work fine but I am curious of their differences. The lines of code for both are pretty much equivalent and they both seem to perform the exact same function and have the same efficiency. Which one is preferable? What would you rather see in production code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would much rather see `Task<T>` based code:

- It provides for composition more easily; for example, it's reasonably easy to write a method which takes a collection of `Task<T>` tasks and returns another task which represents the majority verdict of those tasks. Likewise you can wait until any one of a collection of tasks has completed, etc.
- It provides more flexible scheduling of where the continuation is run.
- It allows the task itself to be returned with type safety and a lot more information than the somewhat anaemic `IAsyncResult` type returned by `BeginRead`.
- It's simpler to specify error handling and cancellation with tasks than using the Begin/End model.
- `Task<T>` is getting better language support in C# 5 with async/await - if your codebase already uses `Task<T>` pervasively, it'll be *much* easier to take advantage of this

Basically in modern code running on .NET 4, `Task<T>` is the idiomatic way of representing an on-going task. It's a much richer environment to work in than earlier attempts, and I would embrace it if you have the chance. Obviously if you're using .NET 3.5 or earlier, life is a bit harder, but I'm assuming that as you're asking the question, `Task<T>` is an option...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still a bit confused though. I know BeginRead is very efficient because the callback uses an IO completion port rather than blocking. Is ContineWith the same in terms of efficiency in that it does not block and only runs at the same time EndRead would have ran? Also, could you elaborate on how it supports better error handling? Wouldn't I also have to do the same try-catch on both `state.BytesRead += ` lines in each code sample?

Comment: @RyanPeschel: Yes, it doesn't block - otherwise it would be pointless. And no, you wouldn't need the same try/catch, because you could specify one continuation to run on error, another to run on cancellation, and another to run on success - look at the overloads for ContinueWith. You can also *test* the state of a task without just trying to get the result (look at Task.Status). The whole thing is a lot richer, basically. And the async support in C# 5 is wonderful.

Comment: I'm checking out the overloads but I'm not quite seeing what you're getting at. How can I specify a method to run when there is an error/cancellation?

Comment: I think I might have found it.. Would you call ContinueWith multiple times with different functions with the second argument as something like `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` if you want said method to run if there is an error?

Comment: @RyanPeschel: I can't go into detail here as I'm on a phone, but look at TaskContinuationOptions. EDIT:just seen your edit; yes, that's what I was talking about. Note that you can attach multiple continuations.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It seems to work. Just to be sure, can you confirm something like this to be proper? They're called side-by-side. `read.ContinueWith(Read, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);` `read.ContinueWith(ReadError, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);`