# Would a ThreadPool or a Task be the correct thing to use for a server?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I'm trying to convert some code from just creating a new thread to run a function to making it use a Thread Pool or even the Task Paralleling Library.  I'm doing this since I know that despite the Worker Thread's Function may run indefinitely (in theory), each thread will spend most of it's time doing nothing.  I also want something to minimize the overhead for the creation and destruction of the Worker Threads, as connections may timeout or new ones get created.  That - and seeing CLRProfiler show 7836 threads were finalized in/after a 62 hour test run is a little unnerving, with a single (if finicky) device sending a message.

Here's what I want to do:

Main Thread.

1.) Have a TCPListener accept a TcpClient

2.) Fire off a Worker Thread which uses that TcpClient

3.) Go back to step 1 if we haven't been told to stop.

Worker Thread (To used in the Pool/Tasks)

1.) Check to see if we have a message from the TcpClient

2.) If so, parse message, send off to database, and sleep for 1 second.

3.) Otherwise, sleep for 1 millisecond.

4.) Go back to step 1 if we haven't been told to stop and have not timed out.

Here's the original approach:

```
private AutoResetEvent connectionWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private static bool stop = false;

private void MainThread()
{
    TcpListener universalListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, currentSettings.ListeningPort);
    universalListener.Start();

    while (!stop)
    {
        IAsyncResult result = universalListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(WorkerThread, universalListener);
        connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        connectionWaitHandle.Reset();
    }
}

private void WorkerThread(IAsyncResult result)
{
    TcpListener listener = result.AsyncState as TcpListener;

    if (listener == null)
    {
        connectionWaitHandle.Set();
        return;
    }

    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
    connectionWaitHandle.Set();

    NetworkStream netStream = null;

    bool timedout = false;

    try
    {
        while (!timedout && !stop)
        {
            if (client.Available > 0)
            {
                netStream = client.GetStream();

                //Get and Parse data here, no need to show this code
                //The absolute fastest a message can come in is 2 seconds, so we'll sleep for one second so we aren't checking when we don't have to.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                //Sleep for a millisecond so we don't completely hog the computer's resources.
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

            if (/*has timed out*/)
            {
                timedout = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //Log Exception
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing the universalListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(...) et. all with

```
(new Task.TaskFactory.FromAsync<TCPClient>(universalListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient, universalListener.EndAcceptTcpClient, universalListener).ContinueWith(WorkerThread);
```

as well as removing the AutoResetEvent connectionWaitHandle code, but the Worker Thread seemed to only fire once.

I'm also a little unsure if I should even try to use a Thread Pool or a Task, as everything I could find about Thread Pools and Tasks (official documentation or otherwise) seems to indicate they should be used with threads that have an extremely short lifespan.

My questions are:

1. Is the Thread Pool or even Tasks from the Task Parallel Library appropriate for Long-lived, but mostly wheel spinning, Threads?
2. If so, how would I best implement the correct pattern?
3. If so, did I have the right idea on using TaskFactory.FromAsync(...).ContinueWith(...)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the TPL will use the Thread Pool.  So, either way you are using the Thread Pool.  The question is just which programming model you use to access the pool.  I strongly suggest TPL, as it provides a superior programming abstraction.

The threads in your example are actually not *spinning* (burning CPU cycles), but rather *blocking* on a wait handle.  That is quite efficient and does not consume a thread while blocked.

**UPDATE**

The TaskFactory.FromAsync(...).ContinueWith(...) pattern is appropriate.  For a great list of reasons, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7578998/141172).

If you are using C# 5 / .NET 4.5, you can use async/await to express your code pattern even more compactly.

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/11/22/c-5-0-rise-of-the-task.aspx

Comment: Ok, so it would be a good idea to use TPL for this?  I would like to re-iterate that a Worker Thread wouldn't stop after receiving a message, only after either the TCPClient times out or the program is told to stop.  And is TaskFactory.FromAsync(Accept TCPClient).ContinueWith(Worker Thread) the right way to go?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.  I'll give it another shot and have it run over night to see if it works properly.

Comment: @Tory I also busy developing a communications server using the TPL and it seems to be working quite well. I just recently started using the async/await patterns in .NET 4.5 (still trying to get my head around it, but it looks very promising). We have not been in a position to do stress testing and we really hope at this time we would not need to much tweaking when it comes to that. I would love to know what your findings are in your tests.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine.  One of my biggest concerns was the massive creation and destruction of Threads (7836 for one finicky connection).  Doing a minor stress test of 10 simulated finicky connections over night only produced 1691 (quite the improvement) as well as less Gen0 garbage collection than 10x (~30 vs 144).  Though I did have to split it into Task<TcpClient> t = Task.Factory.FromAsync<TcpClient>(...); t.Wait(); t.ContinueWith(...); so the Factory wouldn't pump out a ton of tasks and thus crash the program from memory starvation.

Comment: @Tory: The nice thing about the thread pools is that threads are not created and destroyed, but rather reused.  True their state has to be re-initialized, but their stack memory allocation etc. is already setup.